# testing with jest to update a react state inside a rejected promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323103/updating-state-during-initialization-of-a-react-hook-test). I have made a few changes that simplifies the question(I believe) and changes it drastically.

I have seperated creating the hook and initialization of midi events.

```
describe("midiConnection", () => {
    it("Should fail", () => {
        const midiPorts = renderHook(() => { return MidiConnection()})
        act(() => {
            midiPorts.result.current.enable()
        })
        console.log(midiPorts.result.current.error)
    })
})
```

```
export function MidiConnection() {
    const {array: midiInputs, push: midiPush, filter: midiFilter} = useArray(["none"])
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | undefined>();
    function enable() {
        WebMidi.addListener("connected", (e) => { if (isInput(e)) {midiPush(e.port.name)}});
        WebMidi.addListener("disconnected", (e) => {
            e.port.removeListener()
            if (isInput(e)) {midiFilter((str) => {return str != e.port.name})}
        });
        // setError("this is a test")
        WebMidi.
        enable().
        catch((err) => {
            // console.log("test")
            // setError(err)
        })
    }
    return ({ports: midiInputs, error, enable})
}
```

the warning is still;

```
Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
```

In addition to seperating out some of the logic I have also experimented with placing `setError()` on other lines to see if I can trigger the warning (the commented out comments.)

It appears that the warning is only triggered when I try to update the state when the promise from `enable()` is rejected.

What can I do to stop this error from happening?

EDIT: I have created a working replica of this in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-butterfly-e72w5b?file=/src/App.test.js), which you will see if you go to tests and look at the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook is async so u need to wait for the next update. [Here is the docs that talks more about it](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async).

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks/dom";
import CHook from "./../hook/CHook";

test("This is a test", async () => {
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => CHook());
  act(() => {
    result.current.update();
  });
  await waitForNextUpdate();
  console.log(result.current.error);
});
```

[Here is the link to a fixed sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-aryabhata-fspcek?file=/src/App.test.js:0-328)